# Hyperref not working (participants: acro, cleverref, pgfplots, biber). Also not working: '\documentclass[final]'

Tags: hyperref, biber, draft, acro

I am writing on my thesis and I can't get it to work with `\documentclass[final]{scrreprt}`. `pdflatex` only passes when the draft option is enabled. 
Also I am not able to use the `hyperref` package. I don't see any errors but links and `hypersetup`s don't grasp. I did trial by error for a long time but I can't get it to work. So my only Idea left is to ask here and provide my entire preamble.

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
DIV10,
a4paper,
oneside,
titlepage,
parskip=half,
headings=normal, 
listof=totoc, 
bibliography=totoc, 
%index=totoc,
draft=true % 
]{scrreprt}
\newcommand*\iffdraft[2]{%
\ifdim\overfullrule>0pt
#1%
\else
#2%
\fi
}
```

Then I load a text document with definitions like `\newcommand{\title}{Not working thesis}` followed by the .tex file with the following packages:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\usepackage[
    automark, 
    headsepline, 
    ilines 
]{scrpage2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
greek,
english,
]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{relsize} 

\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage[
%dvips,
%final
]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,xfrac,nicefrac,units}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[
%prefixsymbolic=false,
load=accepted,
repeatunits=false,
trapambigrange=false,
%input-symbols=()
]{siunitx}%

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}

%\usepackage{floatflt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=TikzPictures/]

\usepackage{standalone} 

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}
% \usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[normal]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[
%natbib=true,
backend=biber,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
sorting=none,
maxnames=2]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{References}

\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\usepackage[chapter]{easy-todo}

\usepackage[
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red, 
    anchorcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue, 
    filecolor=magenta, 
    menucolor=red, 
    urlcolor=cyan, 
%     linkcolor=black, 
%     anchorcolor=black,
%     citecolor=black, 
%     filecolor=black, 
%     menucolor=black, 
%     urlcolor=black, 
     %backref,
     unicode,
     plainpages=false, 
     pdfpagelabels, 
     hypertexnames=false, 
     linktocpage 
     %draft=false
]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
     pdftitle={\tile \subtitle},
     pdfauthor={\author},
     pdfcreator={\author},
     pdfsubject={\title \subtitle},
     pdfkeywords={\title \subtitle},
     }

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  page-ref    = none,% Seitennummer in Klammern
  extra-style = comma,% extra-Informationen mit Komma anhÃ€ngen
  only-used   = false,% fÃŒr das Beispiel auch die nicht verwendeten in die Liste aufnehmen
  sort        = true,  % Liste sortieren
  hyperref  = {true}
}
\input{acro.tex}     

\usepackage[english]{cleveref}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcolumntype{w}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
```

This is the example of how the pdf document is created by now. 
Beside of named problems I don't see problems at the moment. 
Furthermore I am using `Biber` for my Bibliography.
I do hope that this can reproduce my problems. 
I am thankful for any feedback.

Comment: To figure out what is going on, create a *Minimum* (non-)Working Example. Doing so may find the problem. If not, post it here. This means code which people can *compile* to see the problem. Making it minimal means removing stuff to see if you still get the error. If you do, remove some more. If not, trying keeping just the stuff giving the error. And so on. You are definitely loading poor combinations of things here. For example, don't load `graphics` *and* `graphicx`. Also, don't use `geometry` with `scrreprt`/`scrpage2`. And I'm sure some of those others are not really needed...

Comment: What do you mean 'hope'?  You haven't tried..?  Also: you probably want to reconsider the order in which you are loading things.  `hyperref` definitely should go after most other packages, and `inputenc` should go near the top (with `fontenc`); `csquotes` is best loaded before `biblatex`; etc.  Most important, however, is making a complete(!) but minimal example file:  you've got most of it --- probably more preamble than needed, in fact --- but there's no `\begin{document} ... `\end{document}.

Comment: Sorry guys. I could not report back in due to scheduling stress. Furthermore, I was not able to solve the problem with my old preamble. For me, the solution was to switch to the cleanthesis template. I added all my needed packages and everything works flawlessly. Thank you for your help.